# NASM's section directive with vstart=0 has no effect

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, offset

I have the following layout in my .asm file: some code and data which take 0x200 bytes, then 3 sections each of which I start with:

```
[SECTION VSTART=0]
```

I compile it in a raw binary. In the first of these 3 sections I have a far jump:

```
...
jmp 0x10: continue
continue:
mov ax, 8
...
```

The label *continue* in the listing appears at the byte with offset 0x25 from the section beginning. So, as per my understanding, the effect of `VSTART=0` should be that the jump is performed to 0x10:0x25. Here's what I have in the NASM listing:

```
254 00000020 EA[2500]1000            jmp 0x10: word continue
255                                  
256                                  continue:
257                                  
258                                  ;loading the ds
259 00000025 B80800                  mov ax, 8
```

But when I try to run it in Bochs it jumps to 0x10:0x225 as if there was no `SECTION` directive at all. Looking into the binary file confirms that the generated `jmp` (at the offset 0x220 from the beginning of the file) has the following binary form: 0xEA 0x25 0x02 0x10 0x00.

Why is `VSTART=0` ignored by NASM?

Comment: What happens if you specify a section name with something like `section mysection vstart=0`

Comment: `VSTART=0` as the first parameter becomes the literal section name. So you created a section called `VSTART=0` that had no VSTART option so it didn't do anything with the origin point. I verified this was happening when I added the line `[map all file.map]` at the top of the assembly file. If you assemble with the `-f bin` option a map file called `file.map` should be generated, and you should notice that `VSTART=0` became the section name.

Comment: Note for others wondering: `vstart` attributes are not supported by other NASM output formats like `-f obj` but are silently ignored, no warning. However, in this case it appears that the format was `-f bin` and @MichaelPetch answered what happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! @MichaelPetch I didn't realize that NASM doesn't support anonimous sections. I gave names to my sections as you suggested and everything is working now. Additional thanks for mentioning the map file option - I didn't know about its existence.